# Views not scaling correctly unless the device is set in the storyboard (view as: iphone 5s/8/etc)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

It's easiest to describe with screenshots (the "view as" I'm talking about is in the lower right of each image):

Simulator: iPhone 8, storyboard view as: iPhone 8 - works perfectly

[image]

Simulator: iPhone 8 plus, storyboard view as: iPhone 8 - doesn't work

[image]

Simulator: iPhone 8 plus, storyboard view as: iPhone 8 plus - works perfectly

[image]

Example of code that should work correctly, and does when the storyboard is set to that model phone, but doesn't otherwise:

```
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
gradientLayer.colors = [Colors().bgRed.cgColor, Colors().mediumBlue.cgColor, Colors().highlitMedBlue.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.1)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Other examples of failures are when I use view.convert(viewX, to: viewY), and it works/fails in the same circumstances as the above pictures.

What's going on here? Is it just the simulator that's wrong? Am I using autolayout incorrectly? Will this work if I tried it on actually phones, rather than the simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to put the frame line inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
  gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds 
}
```

It works perfectly for the simulator with same setting as storyboard , because the view size of it is considered for rendering until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` comes with correct size of the current simulator/device

Comment: Works, thanks! And your explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the frames incorrectly.
The width and height should be derived from self.view.frame

Try using

```
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

If you wish to use self.view.bounds,

Then try

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
```

let me know if it works.